# Domain name lookup as another domain name

Tags: windows, dns, domain, lookup

In Windows (8.1) `hosts` file contains mappings of IP addresses to host names.
For example:

> 127.0.0.1         example.domain.net

What I want to achieve is to map a domain name to another domain name while the DN lookup takes place. For example:

> example.domain.net            sub.example.domain.net

When the `sub.example.domain.net` gets resolved (by typing into a browser address bar), the `example.domain.net` would get resolved instead to whatever IP with whatever DNS server at `example.domain.net`.

I use a free DDNS service and my sub-domains `sub.example.domain.net` won't get resolved to the right IP as `example.domain.net`. At the free DDNS service, I would have to pay to have all sub-domains resolve to the same record as the parent.

Is there any workaround for this problem? For example a script that updates hosts file automatically, or a browser add-on?

Comment: HOSTS files are for mapping host names to IP addresses - nothing else. So you can't use them to map a host/domain name to another host/domain name.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I know that.

Comment: good, 'cause that fact wasn't clear in your question. Are you trying to make the sub-domains work on the public Internet, or just internally on your LAN? Really though "I don't want to pay" isn't really a problem we can help you with.  What have you tried already?

Comment: Trying to make sub-domains work from the outside. The DDNS provider does not resolve my sub-domains to the same record as the parent domain. I wish to do this automatically on the client PC.

Comment: But only from a specific machine?  I'm trying to get the scope figured out here. Do you want everyone form outside the network hosting the server to be able to access it, or just a single specific external computer/LAN?  If you want the subdomain publically available to anyone, then they need to be in a public DNS, which you'll have to pay for.  If it's (only) a specific LAN that you want to be able to use the sub-domains, then you should set up a private DNS server on that LAN.

Comment: Only from a specific machine. The problem is, that `example.domain.net` got resolved to X IP address, but `sub.example.domain.net` does not (it fails), because it's an extra feature to resolve the sub-domain to the same record `example.domain.net`. I just need to configure a specific machine, PC to use the IP X fetched from `example.domain.net` when resolving `sub.example.domain.net`. Other words, map a hostname to a hostname on a Windows machine.